# Передача внешних переменных в качестве параметров методу объекта

Tags: php

Возможно ли передать методу объекта параметрами значения внешних переменных, если в самом методе для параметров конкретизируется только то, что параметры должны быть массивами?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как конкретизируется, если

```
class foo {
  public function a(array $a){

  }
}
```

То передать можно только массив, но никто не запрещает в этот массив обернуть что угодно.

Comment: у меня используется вместо `array $a` такой вариант - `$a = []`? когда передаю массивы извне в этот метод(асинхронно через `ajax`), он не срабатывает, 500 ошибка

Comment: это не "конкретизируется" , а задание значения по умолчанию

Answer (score 1):

Если вы передаете очень много переменных в функцию, вы делаете что-то неправильно, ведь скорее ваша функция очень большая и выполняет больше чем нужно.

Передавать параметры в метод в виде массива в 99% случаев — **просто отвратительно (!!!)**. Причины следующие:

1. Придется знать/заучивать ключи массива.
2. Редактор кода не подскажет/покажет, что какие аргументы принимает метод.
3. Осложняется phpDoc документирование.
4. В принимающем методе будет "портянка" из проверок и валидаций каждого элемента массива параметров.

**В итоге для разработчика интерфейс метода становится черным ящиком.**

Если класс подразумевает значения некоторых свойств, без определения которых функционирование объекта невозможно в полном объеме, то надо писать сеттеры и геттеры. На каждое свойство. Это хорошая и правильная практика. Сеттеры и геттеры позволяют получать и изменить свойства объекта в процессе исполнения программы.
Класс должен обладать внятным и прозрачным интерфейсом. *Передача массива параметров — это антипод такого класса.*

Когда можно передавать массив с параметрами в функцию или метод? В очень незначительных случаях, когда пропуск того или иного элемента такого массива особо ни на что не повлияет. Или где разработчик не может предугадать, сколько параметров придёт при вызове метода.

Хотите передавать внешние параметры, **используйте классы и передавайте там все параметры**, которые нужны для работы функции. Использовать глобальные переменные в функции, чтобы обращаться к ним внутри функции, в целом такая же ужасная идея, как передача ассоциативного массива.

Comment: Возможно Вы меня неправильно поняли - я не передаю параметры массивом в метод, а просто параметрами метода являются массивы для построения в конечном итоге таблицы. Но за советы спасибо, я только еще учусь ООП и на практике всегда возникает много вопросов.

Comment: "Если класс подразумевает значения некоторых свойств, без определения которых функционирование объекта невозможно в полном объеме, то надо писать сеттеры и геттеры." - если без каких-либо свойств функционирования объекта невозможно, то правильнее будет их обязательно принимать в конструкторе, а не ожидать в сеттере (исключение: объекты в которых необходимы циклические ссылки), дабы избежать temporary coupling и гарантировать, что, если экземпляр будет создан, то это будет валидный экземпляр.

Comment: @IgorKarpenko Верное замечание :) Правильно принимать основные параметры в конструкторе, а дополнительные в сетерах. Подход без конструктора и только с сетерами называется Javabeans, и у него есть минусы, например не устойчивое состояние обьекта.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в области видимости - обращался к объекту из функции, не глобализировав объект.